# Vercel Build error occurred generating static pages

Tags: next.js, vercel

I'm trying to deploy a NextJS project to Vercel but I'm facing a problem. Any of 9 static pages are not prerendering. This is the log error:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/empregados/cadastrar". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at URL.onParseError (node:internal/url:565:9)
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at new URL (node:internal/url:641:5)
    at new SupabaseClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js/dist/main/SupabaseClient.js:71:41)
    at createClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js/dist/main/index.js:35:12)
    at createBrowserSupabaseClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/auth-helpers-shared/dist/index.js:316:46)
    at createBrowserSupabaseClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs/dist/index.js:317:70)
    at /vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/_app.js:609:166
    at Ic (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:59:265)
Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at URL.onParseError (node:internal/url:565:9)
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at new URL (node:internal/url:641:5)
    at new SupabaseClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js/dist/main/SupabaseClient.js:71:41)
    at createClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js/dist/main/index.js:35:12)
    at createBrowserSupabaseClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/auth-helpers-shared/dist/index.js:316:46)
    at createBrowserSupabaseClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs/dist/index.js:317:70)
    at /vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/_app.js:609:166
    at Ic (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:59:265)
info  - Generating static pages (2/9)
Error occurred prerendering page "/empresas-medicas/cadastrar". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at URL.onParseError (node:internal/url:565:9)
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at new URL (node:internal/url:641:5)
    at new SupabaseClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js/dist/main/SupabaseClient.js:71:41)
    at createClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js/dist/main/index.js:35:12)
    at createBrowserSupabaseClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/auth-helpers-shared/dist/index.js:316:46)
    at createBrowserSupabaseClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs/dist/index.js:317:70)
    at /vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/_app.js:609:166
    at Ic (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:59:265)
Error occurred prerendering page "/medicos". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at URL.onParseError (node:internal/url:565:9)
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at new URL (node:internal/url:641:5)
    at new SupabaseClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js/dist/main/SupabaseClient.js:71:41)
    at createClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js/dist/main/index.js:35:12)
    at createBrowserSupabaseClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/auth-helpers-shared/dist/index.js:316:46)
    at createBrowserSupabaseClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs/dist/index.js:317:70)
    at /vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/_app.js:609:166
    at Ic (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:59:265)
Error occurred prerendering page "/empresas-medicas". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at URL.onParseError (node:internal/url:565:9)
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at new URL (node:internal/url:641:5)
    at new SupabaseClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js/dist/main/SupabaseClient.js:71:41)
    at createClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js/dist/main/index.js:35:12)
    at createBrowserSupabaseClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/auth-helpers-shared/dist/index.js:316:46)
    at createBrowserSupabaseClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs/dist/index.js:317:70)
    at /vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/_app.js:609:166
    at Ic (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:59:265)
info  - Generating static pages (4/9)
info  - Generating static pages (6/9)
Error occurred prerendering page "/socios/cadastrar". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at URL.onParseError (node:internal/url:565:9)
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at new URL (node:internal/url:641:5)
    at new SupabaseClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js/dist/main/SupabaseClient.js:71:41)
    at createClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js/dist/main/index.js:35:12)
    at createBrowserSupabaseClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/auth-helpers-shared/dist/index.js:316:46)
    at createBrowserSupabaseClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs/dist/index.js:317:70)
    at /vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/_app.js:609:166
    at Ic (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:59:265)
Error occurred prerendering page "/404". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at URL.onParseError (node:internal/url:565:9)
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at new URL (node:internal/url:641:5)
    at new SupabaseClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js/dist/main/SupabaseClient.js:71:41)
    at createClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js/dist/main/index.js:35:12)
    at createBrowserSupabaseClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/auth-helpers-shared/dist/index.js:316:46)
    at createBrowserSupabaseClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs/dist/index.js:317:70)
    at /vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/_app.js:609:166
    at Ic (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:59:265)
Error occurred prerendering page "/mudar-a-senha". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at URL.onParseError (node:internal/url:565:9)
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at new URL (node:internal/url:641:5)
    at new SupabaseClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js/dist/main/SupabaseClient.js:71:41)
    at createClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js/dist/main/index.js:35:12)
    at createBrowserSupabaseClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/auth-helpers-shared/dist/index.js:316:46)
    at createBrowserSupabaseClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs/dist/index.js:317:70)
    at /vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/_app.js:609:166
    at Ic (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:59:265)
Error occurred prerendering page "/500". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at URL.onParseError (node:internal/url:565:9)
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at new URL (node:internal/url:641:5)
    at new SupabaseClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js/dist/main/SupabaseClient.js:71:41)
    at createClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js/dist/main/index.js:35:12)
    at createBrowserSupabaseClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/auth-helpers-shared/dist/index.js:316:46)
    at createBrowserSupabaseClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs/dist/index.js:317:70)
    at /vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/_app.js:609:166
    at Ic (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:59:265)
> Build error occurred
info  - Generating static pages (9/9)
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
    /
    /_error: /404
    /_error: /500
    /empregados/cadastrar
    /empresas-medicas
    /empresas-medicas/cadastrar
    /medicos
    /mudar-a-senha
    /socios/cadastrar
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:409:19
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
    at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:1345:21
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
    at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:1205:17
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
    at async Object.build [as default] (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:66:29)
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

Locally everything works fine and the build is successful:

```
npm run build

> dashboard@0.1.0 build
> next build

info  - Loaded env from .env
info  - Linting and checking validity of types  
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data  
info  - Generating static pages (9/9)
info  - Finalizing page optimization

Route (pages)                              Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ / (418 ms)                             332 B           213 kB
├   /_app                                  0 B             213 kB
├ ○ /404                                   181 B           213 kB
├ λ /api/contascorrente                    0 B             213 kB
├ λ /api/contascorrente/[id]               0 B             213 kB
├ λ /api/documentos                        0 B             213 kB
├ λ /api/empregados                        0 B             213 kB
├ λ /api/empregados-observacoes            0 B             213 kB
├ λ /api/empregados-pagamentos             0 B             213 kB
├ λ /api/empregados-pagamentos/[id]        0 B             213 kB
├ λ /api/empregados/[id]                   0 B             213 kB
├ λ /api/empresas-medicas                  0 B             213 kB
├ λ /api/empresas-medicas/[id]             0 B             213 kB
├ λ /api/enderecos                         0 B             213 kB
├ λ /api/enderecos/[id]                    0 B             213 kB
├ λ /api/medicos                           0 B             213 kB
├ λ /api/medicos/[id]                      0 B             213 kB
├ λ /api/socios                            0 B             213 kB
├ λ /api/socios/[id]                       0 B             213 kB
├ λ /empregados                            3.35 kB         216 kB
├ ○ /empregados/cadastrar (362 ms)         1.72 kB         250 kB
├ ○ /empresas-medicas (415 ms)             1.78 kB         227 kB
├ λ /empresas-medicas/[id]                 4.3 kB          268 kB
├ ○ /empresas-medicas/cadastrar (384 ms)   1.15 kB         233 kB
├ ○ /medicos (372 ms)                      1.67 kB         227 kB
├ λ /medicos/[id]                          662 B           265 kB
├ ○ /mudar-a-senha (394 ms)                762 B           213 kB
├ λ /socios                                3.38 kB         216 kB
├ λ /socios/[id]                           1.7 kB          266 kB
└ ○ /socios/cadastrar (358 ms)             1.28 kB         233 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all              213 kB
  ├ chunks/framework-114634acb84f8baa.js   45.4 kB
  ├ chunks/main-66ca454f7bdf962f.js        27 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-1497eacb955143f3.js  139 kB
  ├ chunks/webpack-36d12a75f0098f30.js     1.04 kB
  └ css/2ec7a21f39c50b69.css               783 B

λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
```

Some of the pages are so simple that its codebase may not be problem, like index.tsx:

**pages/index.tsx**

```
import MainContent from "components/Containers/MainContent";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <MainContent>
      <h1>hello world</h1>
    </MainContent>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

So, how could I fix this problem? The build just work fine locally and I'm able to start the application without any trouble.

Comment: aer you using next.js api folder for server or you created a custom server

Comment: @Yilmaz api folder. But there's no problem on API routes, I think